# Drag and drop file to specific target

Tags: javascript, ember.js, file-upload, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I have a set of elements of media files listed like this.

[image]

I want to upload a a media file from windows explorer to a specific target of this list(for eg- It should be possible to add file above 'Title A' or below 'Title A'... ). How to achieve this?I know how to upload a file and it is achievable for me if it's to add to the end of the list. What I don't get is how to get that specific position which I need to upload.

(If it's a DOM element, I could have used jQuery draggable droppble, but again it's not possible here! :(. )

I am using ember and I have created component and added it after each element

```
abc: $('<div class="bla"></div>'),

didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);  
    var self = this;

$('.xyz').bind("dragenter", function (evt) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var targetElement = $(evt.target).prev();
  var holder = self.get('abc');
  targetElement.after(holder);
});

$('.xyz').bind("dragleave", function (evt) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.bla').detach();
});  

$('.xyz').bind("drop", function (evt) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.bla').detach();
 });
},
```

With this I could successfully add a div below the target element. But with 'dragleave' it's executing every time and hence it's detaching everytime and also if I don't want to drop it or drop outside the window, it's not detaching at all.(something like dragend?)

```
.bla{
   position: relative;
   clear: both;
   cursor: default;
   margin-top: 2px;
   min-height: 32px;
   line-height: 32px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Any help?!

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any attempt? If so, add some code so we can help you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @FrankerZ: Please see the edit and I am happy to provide more info!

Comment: @evgenifotia Why 'keyup' event? Do you mean mouseup event